# O tamanho do nome de uma variável afeta seu peso?

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, memória

Há diferença de tamanho entre isso:

```
string packet1234 = "123";
```

E isso?

```
string packert1234556 = "123";
```

Comment: Sorte que não afeta, senão o pessoal do Java estaria lascado.

Comment: Sem falar uns do Oracle ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Não, definitivamente não. Na verdade após compilar o código o nome da variável até desaparece. Uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é apenas um padrão de projeto bastante conhecido para facilitar o acesso a um endereço de memória. Em linguagens compiladas o nome se transforma em endereços diretos. É uma conveniência de acesso à memória usadas em linguagens ditas de alto nível. Elas são usadas para facilitar o entendimento do código pelo programador. Por isto seus nomes devem ser significativos.

Somente em linguagens **totalmente** interpretadas, que são bem raras, é que poderia fazer alguma diferença mensurável. Mas esta última palavra é chave. Porque poderia mensurar mas não faria diferença real de fato. E isto em linguagens interpretadas que não possuam nenhum tipo de otimização. Coloco isto mais à título de curiosidade, não afeta em nada o C# que é compilada.

Portanto em qualquer linguagem que eu conheça o tamanho do nome da variável não afetará a performance ou consumo de memória significativamente e na maioria dos casos nem mesmo de forma ínfima. A escolha do nome já deveria ser feita pensando na legibilidade mesmo que houvesse algum custo para nomes grandes.

Até há um custo de memória em C# em certas situações onde o nome da variável não é uma variável local comum, já que C# possui diversos metadados. Então um nome maior traria um consumo maior teórico. Mas é uma diferença tão ínfima e só mesmo na sua definição e não no consumo que seria ridículo achar que isto muda alguma coisa. Seria como reclamar que caiu uma gota de chuva quando você está dentro de uma piscina (sem exagero). Eu coloquei para dar a resposta mais correta possível mas dá até medo haver a interpretação que há um custo extra que deva ser minimamente considerado. Tem tantos outros fatores que afetam o programa que pensar nisto é um absurdo.

E se por acaso a preocupação faça algum sentido é melhor programar em Assembly. É bom que seja uma fera nisto para não fazer código pior que um bom compilador em uma linguagem otimizada faria. Mesmo assim duvido que faria sentido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bem esclarecido, obrigado!