# O que é uma variável?

Tags: terminologia, variáveis, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, ciência-da-computação

Usamos variáveis o tempo todo em códigos. É a mesma coisa que aprendemos em matemática? Como funciona a variável nas linguagens de programação?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Essencialmente variável em computação é o mesmo que em matemática, só usamos de uma forma um pouco diferente, pelo menos do jeito que aprendemos sobre variáveis na escola. Variável não precisa fazer parte de uma fórmula como costuma acontecer na matemática.

## Definição

Variável é um nome para um valor. É uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) que usamos para facilitar nosso trabalho de codificação.

Computadores não reconhecem variáveis, este é um conceito de alto nível, é uma abstração criada por humanos para expressar melhor um valor concreto.

Para o computador existem posições de memória onde valores são armazenados e isso é controlado pelo hardware e sistema operacional.

Em geral os sistemas operacionais trabalham com um sistema de memória virtual onde cada processo "enxerga" a memória como se fosse toda sua. Por outro lado, ele não consegue acessar partes da memória que não lhe pertencem. A memória real é uma completa bagunça, mas para o processo parece uma sequência limpinha.

O código vai acessando esses endereços conforme a necessidade. Dados podem estar:

- em uma área estática que não pode ser escrita,
- na [área de pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) de execução que tem controle **automático** do [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101),
- e na área geral que é usada para alocação dinâmica e o tempo de vida deve ser gerenciado pelo seu código (ou do *framework* que usa).

O código de máquina só acessa os endereços puramente. Tanto que em [Assembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101) só usamos endereços. [Internamente as variáveis somem e dão lugar a endereços de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91372/101).

**Variáveis são apenas nomes para posições de memória onde existem valores armazenados**. Também podemos dizer que variável é um local de armazenamento.

## Nomes

O nome da variável que é conhecido como **identificador** ou mesmo **símbolo** é uma referência para um valor de forma direta ou indiretamente. Essa referência é conhecida pelo seu código fonte, mas desaparecerá após a compilação ou interpretação deste código.

Na matemática costumamos usar variáveis de uma letra. Em programação costumamos dar nomes mais significativos já que trabalhamos com problemas muito diferentes, fora do padrão da matemática e comumente temos muitas variáveis em uso.

Algumas variáveis não possuem exatamente nomes, mas sim índice. É o caso de um *array*. Cada elemento do *array* é uma variável que é acessada pelo seu índice em conjunto com a variável que referencia todo o *array*. Um cálculo é feito para achar a posição de memória partindo da posição inicial do *array* e deslocando o índice.

Variáveis podem estar dentro de uma estrutura. Ali também há um deslocamento como o ocorre no *array*, só que ao contrário do *array* cujos elementos são homogêneos (mesmo tipo, mesmo tamanho), uma estrutura de dados é heterogênea.

Nos nomes geralmente pode-se usar letras, números e alguns símbolos, principalmente o `_`. Começar por números costuma ser proibido já que criaria ambiguidade com números literais. A maioria dos caracteres não alfanuméricos são proibidos porque confundiria com operadores e outras construções da linguagem, incluindo espaço que acabaria separando o nome em dois. Algumas linguagens restringem para bem poucos símbolos e qualquer caractere Unicode pode ser usado.

Nomes inválidos:

```
valor total
data-vencimento
12dias
```

Algumas linguagens não diferenciam maiúsculas de minúsculas.

É comum estabelecer-se convenções para os nomes. Tem linguagem que fez isso ter semântica própria no código.

Vários nomes podem referenciar o mesmo local de armazenamento. Obviamente que se o valor neste local muda, todas variáveis terão seu valor alterado (grosso modo).

## Corolário

Variável é um **padrão de projeto** (*design pattern*) tão usado, tão simples, e tão presente em linguagens que ninguém enxerga assim. É um padrão para acessar uma posição da memória. Esse padrão torna independentes nome e valor. Isso cria várias oportunidades para expressar algoritmos complexos de forma **poderosa e flexível**.

Quando a gente diz "vou imprimir a variável", na verdade sempre está querendo dizer "vou imprimir o valor referenciado por essa variável".

Há casos que o valor está referenciado diretamente pela variável, são as variáveis por valor.

Há casos que o valor está referenciado por um ponteiro cuja variável referencia, são as variáveis por referência. Nesse caso o valor real da variável é o endereço de memória que indica onde está o valor que deseja acessar.

É comum nos referirmos ao valor como um **objeto**. Isso nada tem a ver com orientação a objetos.

O valor de uma variável pode eventualmente ser conhecido apenas durante a execução. Seu valor pode ser alterado durante a execução do código, salvo algo nele que crie algum impedimento. Algumas variáveis podem ser declaradas como somente leitura, então o valor é "alterado" apenas uma vez na sua criação.

Variável se diferencia de **constante** principalmente porque a segunda não permite que seu valor seja alterado durante toda execução do código. É possível que uma constante já seja substituída por seu valor eliminando a referência.

Variáveis podem ser **acessadas** (leitura) ou **atribuídas** (escrita).

Variáveis costumam ter [**escopo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).

Em linguagens estaticamente tipadas a **variável terá um tipo** por toda sua existência (pode haver exceções). Em linguagens dinamicamente tipadas a variável tem o tipo do valor que ela referencia naquele momento.

**[Parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)**, para todos os efeitos, são variáveis.

A maioria das linguagens exigem que uma variável seja declarada antes de usá-la. A **declaração** é uma indicação para o compilador reservar espaço na memória para a variável. Durante a declaração já é possível atribuir um valor.

Hoje praticamente não há linguagem que exija que a variável seja declarada no início do seu escopo. No passado isso era necessário para facilitar para o compilador, mas hoje ele consegue detectar todas as declarações em qualquer ponto do escopo e faz a reserva no início dele.

A maioria das variáveis não são obrigatórias de fato, mas não usá-las pode dificultar bastante o que o código terá que fazer, repetindo operações e amontoando coisas. Ao mesmo tempo que elas podem ser úteis, é comum programadores leigos usarem variáveis sem a menor necessidade.

Em alguns casos variáveis podem ser usadas para documentar melhor o código. É uma forma de dar nome para uma fórmula.

Portanto variável é algo que tem um local de armazenamento, com um endereço de acesso, com um valor presente, de um tipo específico e que tem uma visibilidade determinada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 15):

Variável é um nome que guarda um valor, como o Maniero muito bem explicou na sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/181333). Esse valor pode ser de vários tipos e a variável possui escopos de visibilidade que dependem da onde foi originalmente declarada dentro do código.

Os tipos mais comuns de variáveis são: número inteiro, número real, texto, vetores de valores ou coleções e boleano. Na maioria das linguagens você encontrará esses nomes em inglês como *int* ou *integer*, *float*, *string*, *array*/*vector*/*list*/*collection* etc e *bool* ou *boolean*.

Em algumas linguagens conhecidas como fortemente tipadas você precisará especificar o tipo na hora da declaração da variável. Ex: Java ou C++.
Em outras linguagens, chamadas de fracamente tipadas, essa especificação do tipo na hora da inicialização da variável será desnecessária e o tipo será analisado dinamicamente durante o tempo de execução. Ex: PHP e JavaScript.

#### Declaração de variáveis de um modo geral, já sendo inicializadas:

> tipo nomedavariavel = valorqueseraarmazenadonavariavel;

Obs: Ponto e vírgula marca o final da instrução em um grande número de linguagens.

Exemplos de declaração de variáveis em linguagem fortemente tipada (em algoritmo genérico, pois será diferente em cada linguagem):

`int numero = 178000;`

`string nome = "Maniero";`

`float salario = 8000.00;`

`array frutas = ["banana","maçã","pera","uva"];`

`bool estaChovendo = false;`   //aceita como valores false ou true, 0 ou 1

#### Escopo de variáveis

Dependendo do lugar onde a variável seja declarada, outras partes poderão ou não acessá-la/utilizá-la.

Exemplo grosseiro:

```
// variavel declarada globalmente
variavelglobal = "essa var pode ser acessada de qualquer lugar";

// Bloco de código, como uma função
{
   print variavelglobal; // ok
   
   variaveldentrodefuncao = "outra variável, só que esta está sendo declarada dentro de uma função";
}

print variaveldentrodafuncao; // erro, pois essa variavel só existe no escopo onde foi declarada, ou seja, dentro da função
```

Veja explicação detalhada seguindo o link [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135572/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-escopo-e-tempo-de-vida) da resposta do Maniero.

Comment: Legal, sempre bom ter outras respostas.

Answer (score -3):

Uma variável é um nome dado para um espaço na memoria ram que vai registrar um dado a ser utilizado por você em seu programa.

Answer (score -4):

Na programação as variáveis são como chamamos algo que denomina alguns itens que você armazena no programa, podem guardar números, nomes, frases, dados e etc.